# Explanation of files under /etc/NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager

`/etc/NetworkManager` is an important directory where NetworkManager saves its configs. I want a complete list of what every file is for.

All files under this directory on my laptop is

```
$ tree
.
├── conf.d
├── dispatcher.d
│   ├── no-wait.d
│   ├── pre-down.d
│   └── pre-up.d
├── dnsmasq.d
├── dnsmasq-shared.d
├── NetworkManager.conf
└── system-connections
    ├── Family 2.nmconnection
    ├── Starbucks.nmconnection
    ├── StudentOffice.nmconnection
    └── SunYouran.nmconnection
```

I believe that by answering this question, I can have a better understanding of how the network works in Ubuntu.

Comment: Ask ubuntu is a Q&A site - I don't see a question here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because there is no question submitted

Comment: @24601 The question naturally arises in the discussion: "what do files under `/etc/NetworkManager` do". It is like "what is every directory under root, such as `/etc`, `/log`, used for, but much specific.

Comment: The point of the comments is: you should ask the question, but then write out the answer as an Answer, not as part of the body of your question. So edit your question to retain only the problem, then copy the answer in a separate Answer and you will be fine. Otherwise will need to be closed.

Comment: Use the standard Software WTF Procedure: For each file you're concerned with, `dpkg -S filename` shows which package provided the file. For each package listed above, `dpkg -L package` will show all the files installed by the package. Read the `README*` files, investigate the others (`file`, `less`,`readelf`,...).

Comment: @vanadium I remembered that when I search answers on StackOverflow, it is painful to read very long questions. So I agree to move major things into the answer and keep the question brief.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you! I used to search blindly on the internet and read `man package`. Now I know `dpkg` can provide lots of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vanadium provided a general way for investigating files' usage.

1. For each file you're concerned with, `dpkg -S filename` shows which package provided the file. Directories can also be fed into `filename`, but a full path to the directory is needed.
2. For each package listed above, `dpkg -L` package will show all the files installed by the package.

So for files under `/etc/NetworkManager`

- `dispatcher.d`

  All execute scripts in this directory or its subdirectories will be executed by NetworkManager in alphabetical order in response to network events. Each script receives two arguments, the first being the interface name of the device an operation just happened on, and second the action. For example, the following script disable offload features of temporary network adapters

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # file: /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/80-disable-offload.sh
  # usage: diable offload when eno1/enp0s31f6 is up
  interface=$1
  event=$2
  if [[ $interface == "eno1" || $interface == "enp0s31f6" ]] && [[ $event == "up" ]]; then
    TOE_OPTIONS="rx tx sg tso ufo gso gro lro rxvlan txvlan rxhash"
    for TOE_OPTION in $TOE_OPTIONS; do
        /sbin/ethtool --offload $interface $TOE_OPTION off
    done
  fi
  exit 0
  ```
- `NetworkManager.conf`

  The default content on my machine is

  ```
  [main]
  plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
  dns=default

  [ifupdown]
  managed=false

  [device]
  wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
  ```

  where

  - `ifupdown` is the plugin used on the Debian and Ubuntu distributions, and reads Ethernet and Wi-Fi connections from /etc/network/interfaces.
  - `keyfile` is the generic plugin that supports all the connection types and capabilities that NetworkManager has. It writes files out in an .ini-style format in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.
  - `[ifupdown] manage` is set to `false` as default. If set to false, then any interface listed in /etc/network/interfaces will be ignored by NetworkManager. (My question: how can network-manager manager networks as this is set to `false`?)
- `conf.d`

  Users can add additional .conf files to this directory because `NetworkManager.conf` may be erased by a software update.
- `system-connections` stores information about connections such as wifi. It is managed by `keyfile` plugin as explained above. These are the connections one edits in `nmtui`.
- `dnsmasq.d` and `dnsmasq-shared.d`

  When the dnsmasq plugin is enabled, files in these two folder controls its behavior. For an example of how to enable it and a simple configuration, see [Using the NetworkManager’s DNSMasq plugin](https://fedoramagazine.org/using-the-networkmanagers-dnsmasq-plugin/).

Answer (score 2):

Docs for `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
are found here:

https://networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/NetworkManager.conf.html

There is a man page as well, on the site I had to turn off the css to read it:

`⏵ man NetworkManager.conf`

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/latest/en/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html